Java bytecode if condition in loop
I am working on a java decompiler, and today I found a class file, here is the source code of the class file after decompiled
loop {
   if ([ 119            ifeq] var_17_9.hasNext() /* target: 148 */) {
      [ 129          astore] Object var_12_10(1) = var_17_9.next();
      if ([ 142            ifeq] c0.v(var_18_8, (String)var_12_10, 0) /* target: 112 */) {
         [ 145            goto] goto 151;
      }
   }
   else {
     [ 149          astore] Object var_12_12(1) = null;
   }
   if ([ 153       ifnonnull] var_12_12 == null /* target: 161 */) {
     [ 157        istore_2] var_2_11(0) = 1;
   }
   else {
     [ 162        istore_2] var_2_11(0) = 0;
   }
   if ([ 164            ifeq] var_2_11 /* target: 177 */) {
     [ 171 invokeinterface] var_13_3.add(var_14_7);
   }
}


javap's output
       112: aload         17
       114: invokeinterface #91,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
       119: ifeq          148
       122: aload         17
       124: invokeinterface #94,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
       129: astore        12
       131: aload         18
       133: aload         12
       135: checkcast     #96                 // class java/lang/String
       138: iconst_0
       139: invokestatic  #99                 // Method yo4/c0.v:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z
       142: ifeq          112
       145: goto          151
       148: aconst_null
       149: astore        12
       151: aload         12
       153: ifnonnull     161
       156: iconst_1
       157: istore_2
       158: goto          163
       161: iconst_0
       162: istore_2
       163: iload_2
       164: ifeq          177
       167: aload         13
       169: aload         14
       171: invokeinterface #105,  2          // InterfaceMethod java/util/Collection.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
       176: pop

first I want to know how to write such if statement like offset 142
ifeq jump back to 112 , its a continue
next instruction 145 is a goto
or which version of jdk can compile if statement like this

continue with label?

@talexmovedtoCodidact ifeq's jump is continue, no label there

isn't goto 151 jumping to (after) the end of the if-else ? (but sorry, not sure if I do understand that output)

@user85421  goto 151 is end of if-else

wasn't that what you asked, that is, how there is  goto 151 as instruction 145? I think you must clarify the question ... not clear what exactly you are asking!

@user85421 I want to know how to write java code that can compile into something like this

I still do not fully understand "this"output, maybe an output like from javap would be easier to understand (at least for me);  but 1) I believe it maybe something like while () { if () { ... if () break; } else { ... } }; 2) that is also very implementation/version/... dependent and can changed (or optimized)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"how to write such if statement like offset 142" - I believe that is basically if ( ...  ) break; at the very end of the loop - the compiler invert the condition and use it to jump back to the start of the loop  (instead of using the direct condition to jump out of the loop and needing a second jump to jump back)

@user85421 i wrote lots of example like you said, but it doesn’t work, now i guess the class file may be modified by something like java asm tools, thanks for your reply

or created by some non-java compiler (kotlin, scala, ...)

@user85421 I finally found the source of the class file. It is a class in the jar converted from the dex file of the apk through dex2jar.
